capture hash value from git log --oneline --graph using regex
When running git log --oneline --graph you can get something like this
*   7e5dbb0 Merge
|\
| * c873a96 My
| * f5817ba Amazing
* | f6a34ac Feature
|/
* f5a51ce Other stuff

I want to take that and only capture the hash value of the commit
In theory, the regex statement [^a-f0-9]*([a-f0-9]+).* should be able to do the job but for some reason, I can't get it to work through sed
git log --graph --oneline | sed 's/[^a-f0-9]*([a-f0-9]+).*/\1/'

I think this could maybe be done with awk or grep as well I just can't wrap my brain around it.

What is your expected output?

To use unescaped parentheses as capturing ones, you need to use -E with sed.

If you just want the hash then why not simply git log --pretty=format:"%h"?
